# how to acces colour of individual pixels using SOIL in cpp

Tags: c++, soil

I would like to access the RGB valuas from individual pixels. I know I can get an unsigned char array by calling

```
unsigned char* pixels = SOIL_load_image(picturename.c_str(), &_w, &_h, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
```

However I dont understand what these chars mean. The documentation says:

```
// The return value from an image loader is an 'unsigned char *' which points
// to the pixel data. The pixel data consists of *y scanlines of *x pixels,
// with each pixel consisting of N interleaved 8-bit components; the first
// pixel pointed to is top-left-most in the image. There is no padding between
// image scanlines or between pixels, regardless of format. The number of
// components N is 'req_comp' if req_comp is non-zero, or *comp otherwise.
// If req_comp is non-zero, *comp has the number of components that _would_
// have been output otherwise. E.g. if you set req_comp to 4, you will always
// get RGBA output, but you can check *comp to easily see if it's opaque.
```

However when I load an 10 by 10 pixels image to test it i get an huge ammound of chars in the array (almost 54000) this seems way too much. How do i get the individual pixel colour that I can do something like this:

```
int colourvalue = pixel[y*width+x];
```

i cant seem to find this

Comment: How are you measuring the number of characters in the array? The size should be width*height*num_of_components.

Comment: Also, `pixel[y*width+x]` won't work because you're not taking into account the number of components. You need `pixel[(y*width+x)*num_of_components]`, which will get you the first component of the pixel at `x,y`.